# software for frame images to video with changing framerate?

Tags: software-recommendation, framerate, time-lapse, stop-motion

I've got some frames that were captured over 24h at 2 frames a min.

I want to convert them to video BUT with different playback speeds depending on when they were shot.

I want to be able to use different framerates for different periods of the video.

Each hour has 120 frames so playback of each hour different FPS would take:
    
`|------------------|
| frames |  play   |
|--------|---------|
|   1    | 120 Sec |
|   2    | 60 Sec  |
|   3    | 40 Sec  |
|   4    | 30 Sec  |
|   5    | 24 Sec  |
|   6    | 20 Sec  |
|   8    | 15 Sec  |
|   10   | 12 Sec  |
|   12   | 10 Sec  |
|   15   | 8 Sec   |
|   16   | 8 Sec   |
|   20   | 6 Sec   |
|   24   | 5 Sec   |
|------------------|`

Something like this:

[image: 1]]

Each hour/120 frames at different speeds, this setup would play a day back in just under 9min.

any ideas where I can find software that would let me do this? preferably adjusting the speed via a graph/equalizer setup?

Comment: This but on a PC! https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/slow-fast-slow-control-speed/id727309825?mt=8

Comment: You can try [slowmovodeo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/), a standalone app or [Twixtor](http://www.revisionfx.com/products/twixtor/) for After Effects

Comment: If you know any scripting you could create duplicates to pad the frames out so that there were an even number of frames per minute (with appropriate renaming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really late response but I just stumbled onto the question.

The software you're looking for is Adobe After Effects.

Inside After Effects, you'll end up using the effect called "Time Remapping".

1. Open After Effects
2. Import all your frames as an image sequence
3. Create a composition(whatever resolution/framerate you'd like)
4. Drag your image sequence into the comp(or timeline)
5. In the effects panel, find the time remapping effect and drag it onto your image sequence
6. Go to the effects tab and it should show you the time remapping effect.  Add a keyframe using the stopwatch
7. Add as many keyframes as you need and adjust them to the speed you want depending on where you're at in the video
8. When you're ready to move to the "graph view" select the "graph editor" button

If you're having trouble just google "Time Remapping in after effects" and "Graph Editor view in After Effects" and you should find what you're looking for.

Comment: Welcome to the site matty :) I'm sorry, but *link only answers* are discouraged as if the link goes down then so does the answer. Please include at least some of the steps that the link includes here on the answer. Thanks. Anyway, enjoy video.se!

Comment: Hi @poor . I have updated my answer. Sorry for the link, didn't know that would be a problem.

Comment: Hi Matty, thanks for the more detailed answer. this is definitely what I was looking for!